# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in len()

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the length of a list using the inbuilt len() function but getting a TypeError. 
My code:

```
lst1=[1,2,3,4]
length=len(lst1)
print (length)

Error:
lst1=[1,2,3,4]
length=len(lst1)
print (length)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-42-5e2d2a78a7ce>", line 2, in <module>
    length=len(lst1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I have found similar questions but the answers stated that the problem was using a function name as a variable too, which is not what I'm doing. I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: Write '%whos' command and check results, probable you are re writed the 'len' function

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted in the question in correct.
The following code will never throw you any errors.

```
lst1=[1,2,3,4] 
length=len(lst1)
print(length)
```

However, If you have ever mistakenly used `length()` instead of `length`. i.e

```
print(length())
```

You'll get the error what you've mentioned.
Because `lst1` is a list. Only `int` thing I see here is `length`.

**So once do check your code properly.**

Comment: Thanks Nandan for clarifying that the code snippet is right. However, no matter what I tried it threw the same error. I restarted the spyder application and it works now :)